# Why does Parallel.Foreach create endless threads?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library

The code below continues to create threads, even when the queue is empty..until eventually an OutOfMemory exception occurs.  If i replace the Parallel.ForEach  with a regular foreach, this does not happen.  anyone know of reasons why this may happen?

```
public delegate void DataChangedDelegate(DataItem obj);

public class Consumer
{
    public DataChangedDelegate OnCustomerChanged;
    public DataChangedDelegate OnOrdersChanged;

    private CancellationTokenSource cts;
    private CancellationToken ct;
    private BlockingCollection<DataItem> queue;

    public Consumer(BlockingCollection<DataItem> queue) {
        this.queue = queue;
        Start();
    }

    private void Start() {
        cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        ct = cts.Token;
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() => DoWork(), ct);
    }

    private void DoWork() {

        Parallel.ForEach(queue.GetConsumingPartitioner(), item => {
            if (item.DataType == DataTypes.Customer) {
                OnCustomerChanged(item);
            } else if(item.DataType == DataTypes.Order) {
                OnOrdersChanged(item);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried running the foreach with a low parallelism degree (like 4, 8, etc.) and seeing if the problem persists?

Comment: That does limit the number of threads created (but i'm not able to keep up w/ the producers).  What does this mean about the original code then?  Should the TPL pool manage this properly?

Comment: How do you instantiate the consumer? Are you doing this in a loop perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think `Parallel.ForEach()` was made primarily for processing bounded collections. And it doesn't expect collections like the one returned by `GetConsumingPartitioner()`, where `MoveNext()` blocks for a long time.

The problem is that `Parallel.ForEach()` tries to find the best degree of parallelism, so it starts as many `Task`s as the `TaskScheduler` lets it run. But the `TaskScheduler` sees there are many `Task`s that take a very long time to finish, and that they're not doing anything (they block) so it keeps on starting new ones.

I think the best solution is to set the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism`.

As an alternative, you could use TPL Dataflow's `ActionBlock`. The main difference in this case is that `ActionBlock` doesn't block any threads when there are no items to process, so the number of threads wouldn't get anywhere near the limit.

Comment: GetConsumingPartitioner was created specifically for use by BlockingCollection with Parallel.ForEach, check http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/06/9990420.aspx

Comment: Yes, I did read that. It does avoid some problems that you have with `GetConsumingCollection()`, but not all of them.

Answer (score 3):

The Producer/Consumer pattern is mainly used when there is just one Producer and one Consumer.

However, what you are trying to achieve (multiple consumers) more neatly fits in the Worklist pattern. The following code was taken from a slide for unit2 slide "2c - Shared Memory Patterns" from a parallel programming class taught at the University of Utah, which is available in the download at http://ppcp.codeplex.com/

```
BlockingCollection<Item> workList;
CancellationTokenSource cts;
int itemcount

public void Run()
{
  int num_workers = 4;

  //create worklist, filled with initial work
  worklist = new BlockingCollection<Item>(
    new ConcurrentQueue<Item>(GetInitialWork()));

  cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
  itemcount = worklist.Count();

  for( int i = 0; i < num_workers; i++)
    Task.Factory.StartNew( RunWorker );
}

IEnumberable<Item> GetInitialWork() { ... }

public void RunWorker() {
  try  {
    do {
      Item i = worklist.Take( cts.Token );
      //blocks until item available or cancelled
          Process(i);
      //exit loop if no more items left
    } while (Interlocked.Decrement( ref itemcount) > 0);
  } finally {
      if( ! cts.IsCancellationRequested )
        cts.Cancel();
    }
  }
}

public void AddWork( Item item) {
  Interlocked.Increment( ref itemcount );
  worklist.Add(item);
}

public void Process( Item i ) 
{
  //Do what you want to the work item here.
}
```

The preceding code allows you to add worklist items to the queue, and lets you set an arbitrary number of workers (in this case, four) to pull items out of the queue and process them.

Another great resource for the Parallelism on .Net 4.0 is the book "Parallel Programming with Microsoft .Net" which is freely available at: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963553

Comment: +1 Please help me out.  I cannot figure out how to get the book free from that link.

Comment: @Blam Just click at the sections in the left menu.

Answer (score 1):

Internally in the Task Parallel Library, the Parallel.For and Parallel.Foreach follow a hill-climbing algorithm to determine how much parallelism should be utilized for the operation.

More or less, they start with running the body on one task, move to two, and so on, until a break-point is reached and they need to reduce the number of tasks.

This works quite well for method bodies that complete quickly, but if the body takes a long time to run, it may take a long time before the it realizes it needs to decrease the amount of parallelism.  Until that point, it continues adding tasks, and possibly crashes the computer.

I learned the above during a lecture given by one of the developers of the Task Parallel Library.

Specifying the MaxDegreeOfParallelism is probably the easiest way to go.

Comment: `ThreadPool` uses hill-climbing, not `Parallel.ForEach`. That starts as many `Task`s as the `TaskScheduler` will let it run. And since here it seems the `Task`s can block for a (relatively) long time, that will be a high number. But yeah, MDOP is probably the best thing to do here.