# Throttling producer/consumer pattern leads to deadlock

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, producer-consumer

Got some help here on Stackoverflow earlier this week which resulted in going forward with a producer/consumer pattern for loading processing and importing large datasets into RavenDb.
[Parallelization of CPU bound task continuing with IO bound](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11676807/parallelization-of-cpu-bound-task-continuing-with-io-bound)

I'm now looking to throttle the amount of work units that are prepared in advance by the producers in order to manage memory consumption. I've implemented the throttling using a basic semaphore but I'm having trouble with the implementation deadlocking at a certain point.

I cannot figure out what could be causing the deadlocks. Below is an excerpt of the code:

```cs
private static void LoadData<TParsedData, TData>(IDataLoader<TParsedData> dataLoader, int batchSize, Action<IndexedBatch<TData>> importProceedure, Func<IEnumerable<TParsedData>, List<TData>> processProceedure)
    where TParsedData : class
    where TData : class
{
    Console.WriteLine(@"Loading {0}...", typeof(TData).ToString());

    var batchCounter = 0;

    var ist = Stopwatch.StartNew();

    var throttler = new SemaphoreSlim(10);
    var bc = new BlockingCollection<IndexedBatch<TData>>();
    var importTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        bc.GetConsumingEnumerable()
            .AsParallel()
            .WithExecutionMode(ParallelExecutionMode.ForceParallelism)
            //or
            //.WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)
            .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
            .ForAll(data =>
            {
                var st = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                importProceedure(data);

                Console.WriteLine(@"Batch imported {0} in {1} ms", data.Index, st.ElapsedMilliseconds);
                throttler.Release();
            });
    });
    var processTask = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        dataLoader.GetParsedItems()
            .Partition(batchSize)
            .AsParallel()
            .WithDegreeOfParallelism(Environment.ProcessorCount)
            //or
            //.WithDegreeOfParallelism(1)
            .WithMergeOptions(ParallelMergeOptions.NotBuffered)
            .ForAll(batch =>
            {
                throttler.Wait(); //.WaitAsync()
                var batchno = ++batchCounter;
                var st = Stopwatch.StartNew();

                bc.Add(new IndexedBatch<TData>(batchno, processProceedure(batch)));

                Console.WriteLine(@"Batch processed {0} in {1} ms", batchno, st.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            });
    });

    processTask.Wait();
    bc.CompleteAdding();
    importTask.Wait();

    Console.WriteLine(nl(1) + @"Loading {0} completed in {1} ms", typeof(TData).ToString(), ist.ElapsedMilliseconds);
}

public class IndexedBatch<TBatch> 
    where TBatch : class
{
    public IndexedBatch(int index, List<TBatch> batch)
    {
        Index = index;
        Batch = batch ?? new List<TBatch>();
    }

    public int Index { get; set; }
    public List<TBatch> Batch { get; set; }
}
```

This is the call being made to LoadData:

```cs
LoadData<DataBase, Data>(
    DataLoaderFactory.Create<DataBase>(datafilePath),
    1024,
    (data) =>
    {
        using (var session = Store.OpenSession())
        {
            foreach (var i in data.Batch)
            {
                session.Store(i);
                d.TryAdd(i.LongId.GetHashCode(), int.Parse(i.Id.Substring(i.Id.LastIndexOf('/') + 1)));
            }
            session.SaveChanges();
        }
    },
    (batch) =>
    {
        return batch.Select(i => new Data()
        {
            ...
        }).ToList();
    }
);
```

Store is a RavenDb IDocumentStore. DataLoaderFactory constructs a custom parser for the give dataset.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to debug a deadlock without big arrows that say "blocks here!".  Avoiding debugging the code without a debugger: BlockingCollection already can throttle.  Use [the constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267301.aspx) that takes the `int boundedCapacity` argument and eliminate the semaphore.  Very high odds that solves your deadlock.

Comment: This works without deadlocks but the throttling will not stop at boundedCapacity. I've had it go 75 items over (set it to 10). Not sure why that is?

Answer (score 1):

Can you check the amount of threads you have? Probably you have exhausted the thread-pool due to blocking. The TPL injects more threads than `ProcessorCount` if it thinks your code would deadlock without them. But it can only do so up to a certain limit.

Anyway, blocking inside of TPL tasks is generally a bad idea as the built-in heuristics work best with non-blocking stuff.

Comment: This is on x64 .NET 4.5. Think the threads could be exhausted anyway? I'll take a look.