# Task Parallel Library and SQL Connections

Tags: sql-server, task-parallel-library, connection-pooling

I'm hoping someone can confirm what is actually happening here with TPL and SQL connections.

Basically, I have a large application which, in essence, reads a table from SQL Server, and then processes each row - serially. The processing of each row can take quite some time. So, I thought to change this to use the Task Parallel Library, with a "Parallel.ForEach" across the rows in the datatable. This seems to work for a little while *(minutes)*, then it all goes pear-shaped with...

*"The timeout period elapsed prior to obtaining a connection from the pool. This may have occurred because all pooled connections were in use and max pool size was reached."*

Now, I surmised the following *(which may of course be entirely wrong)*.

The "ForEach" creates tasks for each row, up to some limit based on the number of cores *(or whatever)*. Lets say 4 for want of a better idea. Each of the four tasks gets a row, and goes off to process it. TPL waits until the machine is not too busy, and fires up some more. I'm expecting a max of four.

But that's not what I observe - and not what I think is happening.

So... I wrote a quick test *(see below)*:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim tbl As New DataTable()

    FillTable(tbl)

    Parallel.ForEach(tbl.AsEnumerable(), AddressOf ProcessRow)

End Sub

Private n As Integer = 0

Sub ProcessRow(row As DataRow, state As ParallelLoopState)
    n += 1 ' I know... not thread safe
    Console.WriteLine("Starting thread {0}({1})", n, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    Using cnx As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
        cnx.Open()
        Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
        cnx.Close()
    End Using
    Console.WriteLine("Closing thread {0}({1})", n, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    n -= 1
End Sub
```

This creates way more than my guess at the number of tasks. So, I surmise that TPL fires up tasks to the limit it thinks will keep my machine busy, but hey, what's this, we're not very busy here, so lets start some more. Still not very busy, so... etc. *(seems like one new task a second - roughly)*.

This is reasonable-ish, but I expect it to go pop 30 seconds *(SQL connection timeout)* after when and if it gets 100 open SQL connections - the default connection pool size - which it doesn't.

So, to scale it back a bit, I change my connection string to limit the max pool size.

```
Sub Main()
    Dim tbl As New DataTable()

    Dim csb As New SqlConnectionStringBuilder(My.Settings.ConnectionString)
    csb.MaxPoolSize = 10
    csb.ApplicationName = "Test 1"
    My.Settings("ConnectionString") = csb.ToString()

    FillTable(tbl)

    Parallel.ForEach(tbl.AsEnumerable(), AddressOf ProcessRow)

End Sub
```

I count the real number of connections to the SQL server, and as expected, its 10. But my application has fired up 26 tasks - and then hangs. So, setting the max pool size for SQL somehow limited the number of tasks to 26, but why no 27, and especially, why doesn't it fall over at 11 because the pool is full ?

Obviously, somewhere along the line I'm asking for more work than my machine can do, and I can add "MaxDegreesOfParallelism" to the ForEach, but I'm interested in what's actually going on here.

PS.

Actually, after sitting with 26 tasks for (I'm guessing) 5 minutes, it *does* fall over with the original *(max pool size reached)* error. Huh ?

Thanks.

**Edit 1:**

Actually, what I now think happens in the tasks *(my "ProcessRow" method)* is that after 10 successful connections/tasks, the 11th **does** block for the connection timeout, and then does get the original exception - as do any subsequent tasks.

So... I conclude that the TPL is creating tasks at about 1 a second, and it gets enough time to create about 26/27 before task 11 throws an exception. All subsequent tasks then also throw exceptions *(about a second apart)* and the TPL stops creating new tasks *(because it gets unhandled exceptions in one or more tasks ?)*

For some reason *(as yet undetermined)*, the ForEach than hangs for a while. If I modify my ProcessRow method to use the state to say "stop", it appears to have no effect.

```
Sub ProcessRow(row As DataRow, state As ParallelLoopState)
    n += 1
    Console.WriteLine("Starting thread {0}({1})", n, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    Try
        Using cnx As SqlConnection = fnNewConnection()
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5))
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Exception on thread {0}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
        state.Stop()
        Throw
    End Try
    Console.WriteLine("Closing thread {0}({1})", n, Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)
    n -= 1
End Sub
```

**Edit 2:**

Dur... The reason for the long delay is that, while tasks 11 onwards all crash and burn, tasks 1 to 10 don't, and all sit there sleeping for 5 minutes. The TPL has stopped creating new tasks *(because of the unhandled exception in one or more of the tasks it **has** created)*, and then waits for the un-crashed tasks to complete.

Comment: It looks like you have answered your question. You should post your findings as an answer, not edits to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The edits to the original question add more detail and, eventually, the answer becomes apparent.

TPL creates tasks repeatedly because the tasks it **has** created are *(basically)* idle. This is fine until the connection pool is exhausted, at which point the tasks which want a new connection wait for one to become available, and timeout. In the meantime, the TPL is still creating more tasks, all doomed to fail. After the connection timeout, the tasks start failing, and the ensuing exception(s) cause the TPL to stop creating new tasks. The TPL then waits for the tasks that did get connections to complete, before an AggregateException is thrown.

Answer (score 0):

The TPL is not made for IO-bound work. It has heuristics which it uses to steer the count of threads being active. These heuristics fail for long-running and/or IO-bound tasks, causing it to inject more and more threads without a practical limit.

Use PLINQ to set a fixed amount of threads using `WithDegreeOfParallelism`. You should probably test different amounts. [It could look like this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11677265/122718) I have written much more about this topic on SO, but I can't find it at the moment.

I have no idea why you are seeing *exactly* 26 threads in your example. Note, that when the pool is depleted, a request to take a connection only fails after a timeout. This entire system is very non-deterministic and I'd consider any number of threads plausible.

Comment: Thanks. You make an interesting point re. the creation of tasks with no limit *(because the machine isn't very busy - sleeping mostly)*. However, it would be interesting to note why the 11th task doesn't wait upon attempting to create a connection (because the connection pool is empty), and then bomb after the connection timeout. Tasks 11 through 26 *seem* happy enough, albeit they haven't succeeded in connecting to SQL Server. At which point TPL seems to stop creating tasks for some reason. I think that the 26 is just some arbitrary number.

Comment: Try removing the SqlConnection and only test with sleep. That should reveal the limit that the TPL/thread-pool is willing to go to. The thread-pool max threads are usually set to 250 so this was not the limit. Also, try a sleep of 100ms or so to see how far the TPL goes when it can see regular progress. Progress is an important signal in its algorithm.